# PostgreSQL parallel queries using SPI possible?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12, postgresql-extensions, postgresql-parallel-query

I am using PostgreSQL's [Server Programming Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html) (SPI) to build my postgres extension and execute my query. Please see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi-examples.html) detailed example, or the following simple code sample:

```
int ret = SPI_exec("SELECT * FROM ....", 0);
```

We know that PostgreSQL has parallel query support feature, where a query is executed in parallel using multiple processors. Since the SPI interface hides quite some complexity (communication/locks/cursors/etc), I was wondering whether executing a query in this way limits this parallel query feature in some way or not? Obviously, if it does indeed pose a limit, then maybe it is not worth making use of.

Answer (score 3):

The specific usage in your example does not inhibit parallelism, as can be seen by running `SELECT execq('select count(*) from pgbench_accounts', 0);` and observing the plan via auto_explain.  (I had run `pgbench -i -s20`, so there 2e6 rows).

Other SPI method, like those involving cursors, will inhibit parallelization.